# What does the notation BGR refer to at the byte order level in opencv and ffmepg?

Tags: opencv, graphics, ffmpeg, computer-vision

I see the notation BGR occurs in many places in opencv (e.g. `CV_YUV2BGR_YV12`) and ffmpeg(e.g. `AV_PIX_FMT_BGR24`). My question is what is the byte order in these BGR formats in opencv and ffmpeg in some common little endianness architecture (such as x86/amd64). Is channel B stored in lower address or higher address compared with channel R in these formats?

Thanks!

Comment: They're exactly in the order that the letters suggest. Endianness would only apply for the individual values (e.g. if each channel was 16 bits, rather than 8).

Comment: @DanMašek So for each pixel, channel B is stored at lower address in both opencv and ffmpeg, right?